# closedness of a graph of an unbounded operator between two Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let T be a linear operator from a subset $D(T)$ of a Banach space $X$ to another Banach space $Y$. T is closed if a sequence $x_n$ in $D(T)$ converges to $x \in X$ and the sequence $Ax_n$ converges to $y \in Y$, then $x \in D(T), y\in Y, Ax=y$

In the literature it is often said that T is closed iff the graph of $T$ is closed in $X \times Y$. It seems that the authors consider this trivial, but I cannot see why this hold.

Comment: Try to show that the graph is closed: that is, suppose $(x_n, Ax_n)$ converges to $(x, y) \in X \times Y$, show that $(x, y)$ lies in the graph (which is exactly $x\in D(T)$ and $Ax = y$).

Comment: What you wrote is exactly the definition of $\{(x,y):Ax=y\}$ being sequentially closed.

Comment: 1. A set $F$ in a normed space is closed iff the limit of every sequence in $F$ has its limit in $F$. 2. If $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces, then $X\times Y$ is a normed space and a sequence $(x_n,y_n)\in X\times Y$ converges to $(x,y)$ iff $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$. 3. The graph of $T$ is $\{ (x,Tx) \in X\times Y : x\in\mathcal{D}(T) \}$.

Comment: The 'pair' (x,y) should be in the graph..! I see, thanks!